# Java is this Garbage Collected

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Lets says I have the code in the entity class:

`this.setCurrentState(new NormalState(this));`

if in the normal state class I switch the state of the entity to:

`entity.setCurrentState(new HungryState(entity));`

will the NormalState object be garbage collected event though it holds a reference to the entity that is still active or will it not cause memory leaks?

Comment: At least in my opinion, the way you're calling `setCurrentState` on what *seems* to be different objects might be confusing things...

Comment: Yes, eventually.  Presumably there is only one `currentState` reference variable, and when the new state's reference value is deposited there the old state becomes unreachable.

Comment: @user3580294 the entity class where the first piece of code comes from is set in the constructor and the second piece is used in the normal state class they are both handling the same entity.

Comment: The important thing to know about Java garbage collection is that you don't need to know anything about it.  Except in some fairly rare situations it's all magically taken care of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java's garbage collector removes all objects who don't have any references to them. If calling the `setCurrentState` method replaces the stored reference to the instance of `NormalState` and there isn't another reference to that object in the whole VM, then it's marked as `garbage` and thus, it'll be collected.

Answer (score 1):

The garbage collector removes all objects not being used; if your `NormalState` is not held in a variable, nor being used by code, it will be garbage collected. The `Entity` will also be garbage collected if `NormalState` was the only object containing a reference to it.

For example, given two classes, A and B, where A contains a B as so:

```
public class A {
    B inner = new B();

    public A(B in) {
        inner = in;
    }
}
```

myB will be garbage collected (When our `A` is collected) in the following example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    B myB;

    //setting a value with = returns the value
    //myB = new B() -> myB
    A firstObject = new A(myB = new B())

    //bad coding practice, but the fastest way to clear variables
    firstObject = null; 
    myB = null;
}
```

However, the following will not garbage collect myB because there's still a reference:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    B myB;

    A firstObject = new A(myB = new B()) 
    A secondObject = new A(myB);

    //clear references. secondObject still has a reference to what was myB. 
    //the now unnamed B will not be collected until secondObject changes.
    firstObject = null; 
    myB = null;
}
```

NOTE: It's very annoying trying to name an object; as long as it has a variable, it's easy to say `myB`, but even after your stop calling it `myB`, it's still there in the computer. I don't know what to call it because I stopped calling it `myB` when I did `myB = null;`.